# Using preparedstatement in Text datatypes

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, prepared-statement

In PreparedStatement which method i need to use execute the class

I write a method like

```
public Text getMessage(){
    return message;
}
```

In my class

```
 PreparedStatement ps;
        ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into tblmessage  
 (message) values(?)");
        ps.setString(2, usermsgmodel.getMessage());
        ps.executeUpdate();
```

i got an error in this line saying that "the method getMessage return type is Text, So you setString property cannot accommodate Text value "

```
  ps.setString(1, usermsgmodel.getMessage());
```

Comment: instead of `2` use `1`.

Comment: What is the error? Also use 1 instead of 2, its the first parameter

Comment: chnage the return type of `getMessage()` from `Text` to `String`

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
public Text getMessage(){
    return "Hello"; // or whatever you want to return
}
```

Class :

```
 PreparedStatement ps;
 ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into tblmessage (message) values(?)");
 ps.setString(1, usermsgmodel.getMessage());
 ps.executeUpdate();
```

You are only inserting 1 column data in table so you have to use `1` not `2` in `ps.setString(1,usermsgmodel.getMessage());`

and one question is that where you are setting message ? I don't understand the `return message` line so I have used `Hello`.

Comment: @Haris K.A. : have you defined DB connection properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it works fine.

```
try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hossain?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8;","root","root");
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from UserTable where name=? and password=?");
            ps.setString(1,username);
            ps.setString(2,userpass);
            ps.executeQuery();

        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it as

```
ps.setString(1, usermsgmodel.getMessage());
```