# PreparedStatement for Text datatype

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, prepared-statement

In PreparedStatement i got an error in this line saying that "the method getMessage return type is Text, So setString property cannot accommodate Text value "

I write a method like

```
public Text getMessage(){
    return message;
}
```

In my class

```
 PreparedStatement ps;
        ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into tblmessage  
 (message) values(?)");
        ps.setString(2, usermsgmodel.getMessage());
        ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302740/using-preparedstatement-in-text-datatypes#comment37558778_24302740

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 PreparedStatement ps;
        ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into tblmessage  
 (message) values(?)");
        ps.setString(2, usermsgmodel.getMessage().getValue());
        ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: frnd if i use setText then i got an error "The method setText(int, Text) is undefined for the type PreparedStatement"

Answer (score 0):

`Text` is not type of `java.lang.String` which causing the compile time error.

`PreparedStatement#setString` accepts two parameter

1. parameter index
2. java.lang.String

I think parameter index should be 1 and you need to set the `String` which you need to extract from `Text` value of `getMessage` method.